# How to remove text inside of parentheses with VB script RegExp

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am using a labeling software and I don't want any text inside of parentheses to display on the labels. Here is what I have so far

```
Function RemovePara(TextToBeEdited)
  Set myRegEx = New RegExp
     myRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
     myRegEx.Global = True
     myRegEx.Pattern = "\(([a-z]+?)\)(.+)"
      Set RemovePara = myRegEx.Replace(txt, "")
End Function
```

Now I'm pretty new to this, and when I try to save this code in the labeling software it says "The script did not read the "Value" property, which means the current specified data source was ignored. This may not be what you intended" I had the text I field name I want edited where "TextToBeEdited" is at. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use lookaround assertions.

```
myRegEx.Pattern = "(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\))"
Set RemovePara = myRegEx.Replace(txt, "")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hH5uB7/1)

Comment: Is there a way to make it remove the Parentheses themselves as well?

Comment: then this `\([^()]*\)`

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any clue on how I need to use the "Value" property?